# ストーリーボードを使用しない場合のUICollectionViewとPhotosの使用について

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

swiftで、PhotosとUICollectionViewを利用し、カメラロールにある写真全てを表示するプログラムを作成しているのですが、UICollectionViewの部分でうまくいかず困っています。
ストーリーボードを使用していないせいで、viewWithTag(1)がnilなっているというところまではわかったのですが、対処方法がわからない状態です。
できるだけ、ストーリーボードは使用せずに解決したいと思っています・・・。
お力添えいただけたら幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Photos

class AlbumView: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

var photoAssets = [PHAsset]()
var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    println("now I show you alubum view!")
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //background image
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "cotton-a.png")!)

    // レイアウト作成
    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .Vertical
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5.0
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 5.0
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100)

    getAllPhotosInfo()

    // コレクションビュー作成
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.frame, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
    collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return photoAssets.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
    let asset = photoAssets[indexPath.row]

    var imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView //<-ここでnilになってしまい落ちてしまいます。

    let manager: PHImageManager = PHImageManager()
    manager.requestImageForAsset(asset,
        targetSize: CGSizeMake(120, 120),
        contentMode: .AspectFill,
        options: nil) { (image, info) -> Void in
            println("image is \(image)")

            imageView.image = image
        }
    return cell
}

private func getAllPhotosInfo() {
    photoAssets = []

    var options = PHFetchOptions()
    options.sortDescriptors = [
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)
    ]
    //取得するタイプを選択。今回はimage.
    var assets: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: nil)
    assets.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { (asset, index, stop) -> Void in
        self.photoAssets.append(asset as! PHAsset)
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

第一に、`UITableViewCell`と`UICollectionViewCell`の相違を意識しましょう。前者は、`textLabel`や`detailTextLabel`、`imageView`といったコンテンツビューがあらかじめ用意されていますが、後者は、ほぼ空っぽの状態です。

```
var imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
```

「なければ`imageView`を作る」というプログラムなしに、いきなり`imageView`にアクセスしようとしても、「そりゃないよ」とコンパイラにおこられるだけです。

第二に、`UICollectionViewCell`の[クラスリファレンス](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewCell_class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)UICollectionViewCell)の冒頭をご覧ください。

> To configure the appearance of your cell, add the views needed to
>   present the data item’s content as subviews to the view in the
>   contentView property. Do not directly add subviews to the cell itself.
>   The cell manages multiple layers of content, of which the content view
>   is only one. In addition to the content view, the cell manages two
>   background views that display the cell in its selected and unselected
>   states.

セルにサブビューを貼り付ける場合、`contentView`に`addSubview()`しよう。直接セルに`addSubview()`してはいけない。そう書かれています。

以上から、

1. セルに`imageView`がなければ、`contentView`に`imageView`を貼り付ける。
2. `imageView`にアクセスするには、
   `let imageView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView`
   とする。

という修正をすればいいとわかります。

（個人の考えとして、`UICollectionViewCell`のサブクラスを作って、`imageView`などの主要な構成を作ったほうがいいのではないかと思います。以下、サブクラス`PhotoCell`を作ったサンプルを載せておきます。）

*Xcode 6.4 + Swift 1.2*

```
// import Foundation // UIKitをimportしてあれば、Foundationのimportは不要
import UIKit
import Photos

// 紛らわしさを排除する意味で、AlbumViewをAlbumViewControllerに改名。
class AlbumViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

    var photoAssets = [PHAsset]()
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() // 親クラスの呼び出しは、最初の行で行うようにしましょう。

        println("now I show you alubum view!")

        //background image
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "cotton-a.png")!)

        // レイアウト作成
        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .Vertical
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5.0
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 5.0
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100)

        getAllPhotosInfo()

        // コレクションビュー作成
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.frame, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        // PhotoCellクラスからセルをregistする。
        // collectionView.registerClass(PhotoCell.classForCoder(), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        collectionView.registerClass(PhotoCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell") // クラスの取得は、さっくりselfでOK
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return photoAssets.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoCell // PhotoCellクラスのインスタンスを返す。
        let asset = photoAssets[indexPath.row]

        // var imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView // 不要になったので、削除。

        let manager: PHImageManager = PHImageManager()
        manager.requestImageForAsset(asset,
            targetSize: CGSizeMake(120, 120),
            contentMode: .AspectFill,
            options: nil) { (image, info) -> Void in
                println("image is \(image)")

                // imageView.image = image // 次の行に変更。
                cell.imageView.image = image
        }
        return cell
    }

    private func getAllPhotosInfo() {
        photoAssets = []

        var options = PHFetchOptions()
        options.sortDescriptors = [
            NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)
        ]
        //取得するタイプを選択。今回はimage.
        var assets: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: nil)
        assets.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { (asset, index, stop) -> Void in
            self.photoAssets.append(asset as! PHAsset)
        }
    }

}

// 1クラス1Swiftファイルという制限はなく、1Swiftファイルに複数のクラスを定義してもOK。
class PhotoCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    // プロパティとしてimageViewを宣言しておけば、いちいちviewWithTag()などを使わずにすみます。
    var imageView: UIImageView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // イニシアライザで、imageViewを生成、貼り付け。imageViewの大きさ、ContentModeは、適宜指定してください。
        imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 2.0, y: 2.0, width: frame.size.width - 4.0, height: frame.size.height - 4.0))
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        // contentViewに貼り付ける。
        self.contentView.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    // Storyboardを使用しなくても、このイニシアライザを定義してないと、ビルドを通らない。
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Harawoさん本当にありがとうございます。
詳しい説明に、例のコードのおかげで無事動きました。
サブクラスを作ってみたこともあったのですが、どのようにしていいのかわからず、困っていたので本当に助かりました。
また、複数のクラスを一つのファイルに記入しても良いことや、自分で変更すればいい場所など、細かいコメントのおかげですごくわかりやすかったです。
本当にありがとうございました。